# Is MySQL master-slave replication in sequential consistency pattern?

Tags: mysql

I am learning different patterns of consistency, say, strict/sequential/causal/eventual consistency.

I find the master and slave cluster of MySQL (use InnoDB as the default Engine) seems to be one implementation of sequential consistency: the master of MySQL defines the global sequence of transactional changes with the help of global transaction ID and keeps the Binlog and Redolog in the same order thru the use of grouping commit.

Could someone help me judge the correctness of my understanding?

Comment: I assume you are talking about MySQL's `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  MySQL's NDB uses "eventual consistency" and provides multiple algorithms for specifying what to do when there are inconsistencies.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for this comment, yes the context is InnoDB. It seems to me the most widely used one. But I thought the binblog (mysql server layer) helps with the replication, and so the engine also defines it ?

Comment: My question was partially aimed at others listening in.  The binlog is used by InnoDB for both replication and certain backup techniques.  MariaDB is the same as MySQL in this regard.  NDB and Galera Clustering are different enough to make this discussion not relevant.  ENGINE does matter; InnoDB is the "default".

Comment: @RickJames I see. I've edited the question, and thanks for the additional information, very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Single-threaded MySQL replication is sequentially consistent. On the source instance, events are written to the binary log in the order they are committed. The replica replays them in exactly the same order, whether that's necessary for data integrity or not.

[Multi-threaded MySQL replication](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/multi-threaded-replication-performance-in-mysql-5-7/) has a little more flexibility. It can apply events using multiple threads, which can apply changes in parallel only if they are not causally related. So this is more like causal consistency.